# Storing a list/map of object types in a class in C++11/C++14

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am writing a template for a C++ class (a registry) that has methods like `Create` and `Delete`, which instantiates and stores shared pointers to objects, but the `Create` method returns a reference to the created object rather than the shared pointer itself (the particular paradigm here being that no pointers, even smart pointers, exposed in the public interface).

The object registry that can deal with polymorphic types, in the sense that the registry is specialized for the *base* class and then `Create` is a template function that can be specialized for any polymorphically-derived class of the base class. It then returns a reference to the create object, of the *derived* class. The class also has an ID system, so any objects can be also referred to via that.

I require a `Get` method of type `auto` that can return the object (given its ID) in the same type is was created in. Obviously the objects are stored as a list of shared pointers to the base class, so this requires a `dynamic_cast`.

However, I cannot think of a way of storing the original object type when it is created. I need something akin to a `std::map<[object ID], [object type]>` stored as a member variable for the registry.

I've considered concatenating `std::tuple`s but adding a new object changes its type, so it can't be stored as a member of the registry. I've also considered tricks of having a `typedef` within a new class that inherits from a virtual base class, so it can be stored in a list of pointers to the base class, but then using `dynamic_cast` to access the derived class requires knowing the object type in the first place.

Making a member list of `std::functions` that call another function (instantiated during `Create`) also won't work because the return types are different and `auto` cannot be used within `std::function`. I've also tried various tricks with variadic templates.

All solutions on SO I've seen are unsuitable because these are two methods (`Create` and `Get`) being called wrt the same class, so the information needs to be contained in the particular instance of the class itself.

Is this task impossible?

Comment: You do realize that a reference is really a pointer (just disguised), so your first paragraph requirements contradict themselves?

Comment: It's not a contradiction if they aren't equivalent, which you already said they aren't, so your sentence is itself contradictory. Smart pointers have the addition of connoting ownership: I could return weak pointers, but then there's the faff of having to lock them before use. If I returned shared pointers, the idea of deletion via the registry gets a little less well-defined, as the object will be deleted not after the registry has deleted them but after the local shared pointer that was used to access the object goes out of scope.

Comment: You say you want "no pointers exposed in the public interface", but if you're exposing a reference, you're exposing a pointer.

Comment: I see what you mean. I admit it's a stylistic consideration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not impossible; but you made it impossible.

The system you're asking for doesn't require a lot of technicalities apart from using templates for the `Get` function. Let's break it down:

1. You want to create a system whereby you can instantiate (e.g. `Create`) classes that are of an appropriate 'base' and then store them in an associative-container, in which case you chose `map`.
2. Your map is defined thus:

   ```
   std::map<[object ID], [object type]> m_map;
   ```

   Now, given this information. Why, might I ask, would you want to return a reference to the object? Even more so, your `Create` function can be simplified a lot easier to something like this:

   ```
   void System::create(int id, Base *b)
   {
       m_map.emplace(id, b); // Assuming object ID is of type int
   }
   ```

   If you have your create function implemented thus, then the following is permissible:

   ```
   class Child : public Base
   {
   public:
       Child();
       Child(const std::string &name);
       virtual ~Child();
   };

   int main()
   {
       System s;
       s.create(1, new Child("Roger"));
   }
   ```
3. You are probably not interested in using the manual approach of creating objects, but something more automated. Without introducing new technical measures to our infant System class:

   ```
   static Child *create(const std::string &name)
   {
       return new Child(name);
   }
   ```

   Which allows the following usage:

   ```
   s.create(2, Child::create("William"));
   ```
4. You want to be able to retrieve classes of a derived type based on such. Sans the pun, there's no need to create a highly specialised auto function. You know the type you want to get ''at compile time''; whereas `auto` and `decltype` C++14 are more concerned with types that are unknown until run-time. Assuming you know what type you want, our function is much easier:

   ```
   template<typename T>
   T Get(int id)
   {
       std::map<..>::iterator i = m_map.find(id);

       if (i != m_map.end())
           return dynamic_cast<T>(i->second);
       else return nullptr;
   }
   ```

   Which now allows the following usage, continuing our `int main()`..

   ```
   class Children : public Base
   {
       Children();
       virtual ~Children();
       void add(Child *c);
   };

   int main()
   {
       System s;

       s.create(1, Child::create("Roger"));
       s.create(2, Child::create("William"));
       s.create(3, new Children());

       s.get<Children*>(3)->add(s.get<Child*>(2)); // Add william to group

       return 0;
   }
   ```

   The advantage is that you now have a system that is able to deal with many objects that derive from ''Base'' without having to know which objects actually derive from it! This makes our `System` class very versatile and extensible. It also means that any object-creation methods are the responsibility of the ''Base'' classes; e.g. `Child` and `Children` in our case. For the latter we did not implement an object-factory method because it was not practical at this time.
5. You want to delete an object from your registry, thus:

   ```
   void System::delete(int id)
   {
       m_map.erase(id);
   }
   ```

Now we have a pretty functional registry system that can serve any class. It's important that these registries aren't abused to serve ''too'' generic types. It's better to stratify which family of classes warrants their own registry.

Things to take into account:

When you add objects to your map, they are automatically converted into the Base type, but because of polymorphism the pointer is really pointing to a different location in memory with its own set of values and functionality. This is why it's possible to dynamically convert a type to another so you can get back the derived type. It's in fact a lot better to refer to objects **outside** the system through ids (handles) rather than the references to what they prescribe.

Please note, I'm using raw pointers for this example. If you want to use smart pointers, do take into account that maps already handle memory for you. If they didn't, it wouldn't be possible to use the memory when using the `Get` function. It's a matter of style, but also a highly controversial one. Valid objections.

**Also, very important:**

Consider using `std::unordered_map` *if your system involves getting objects through the `Get` function.* The reason for this is simple: the objects are unordered. This makes it easier to iterate through an unordered_map to retrieve objects contained. Whereas in an ordered_map `std::map` the `Get` function would have to go through all the objects until it finds the one it needs. For this reason: **use `std::unordered_map` when you know you're going to retrieve values/objects; and use `std::map` when you know you're only going to iterate over them.**

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this sort of thing is to make the `Get` method a template method, something like:

```
class Registry {
    template <class T> T &Get(id_t id) {
         ... fetch the smart pointer from the registry
        return dynamic_cast<T &>(*ptr); }
```

This requires the caller of `Get` know what type of object it is getting (and will throw a `std::bad_cast` if it gets it wrong):

```
auto &obj = registry->Get<DerivedType>(id);
```

However, this approach exposes references in the interface, which are really pointers, which you say you want to avoid.

If you really want to avoid exposing all pointers, you need to provide a way of manipulating objects in the registry using only their ids.  One way to do this is to create a `DerivedTypeManipulator` singleton for every derived type you store in the registry, which exposes all the operations on the derived type, but via an id rather than a pointer or reference.

This doesn't really solve the problem of needing to know the derived type in code that needs to do anything specific to a derived type, however.

Comment: Yeah, this is my current implementation! I just thought it would be cool to use the auto keyword and be able to automagically get an object of its original type. This would have use elsewhere in my code, where there's a lot of relationship-setting that doesn't care which derived type the object is.

Comment: If you don't care about the specific derived type, you get a base type reference.

Comment: Ah. I've just learnt that you can get a base type reference even if the base type is abstract, which is good to know.